# argument on 2 vectors without using for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I have 2 vectors

```
  A=[10 22 31 14 55 16 47 18];
  B= [1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2];
```

I want to make a third vector C which contains values of A for values of B=1;
like

```
 C=[10 NaN 31 14 55 NaN 47 NaN]
```

or

```
C=[10 31 14 55 47]
```

I did this using a for loop.
Just want to know if this is doable without using for loop as it may save a lot of computation time. (The vectors with me are really really large

```
for i=1:length (A);
  if B(i)==1;
  C(i)=A(i)
  else C(i)=NaN;
  end;
  end;
```

Comment: got it C=A(B==1)

Answer (score 3):

use boolean logic for indexing. In your case, as you also suggest, you can do it with a simple

```
C = A(B==1);
```

For more complicated conditions, you can also use the function [find()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html), as in

```
C = A(find(B==1));
```

or

```
C = nan(size(A));
C(find(B==1)) = A(find(B==1));
```

Comment: `find` is not at all necessary there. The last expression can be simplified to `C(B==1)=NaN`.

Comment: Agreed, `find` isn't need but I added it for completeness in case OP wants something a bit fancier as well. Also, you should edit your comment, it isn't quite correct (condition should be `(B~=1)`, and doing only this would give you a vector of zeros and nans, not what the OP wants).

Comment: True, I typed that the wrong way around. But I meant you don’t need to generate a vector of NaNs, and then index with the same logic in two arrays. The simpler form would be like this: `C=A; C(B~=1)=NaN`. [Can’t edit my original comment any more, but hopefully this one corrects it.]

Comment: Sure. I don't think it makes a difference if you start everything as a NaN and then copy over values, or copy over values and then replaces NaNs...? Is a copy faster than an initialization?